# Determine the Density Function of $(X_1/X_2)$

Tags: probability-theory

Problem: Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent and uniformly distributed random variables over (0,2). Determine the Density Function of $(X_1/X_2)$.

Here are my thoughts on the problem:
$\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2)$:$(0,2)\times(0,2)$. So $f_1(x_1)=2, f_2(x_2)=f_1(x_2)=2$ for $\forall x_1,x_2\in(0,2)$ such that $f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{f_1(x_1)}{f_1(x_2)}=1$

$y_1=\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ and $y_2=x_2\Rightarrow x_2y_1=x_1, y_2=x_2$. Let $v_1=(x_2y_1)$ and $v_2=y_2$.

Using $g(y_1,y_2)=f(v(y_1,y_2))|J_v(y_1,y_2)|$, (where $J_v$ is the $2\times2$ Jacobian Matrix)$=y_2$

$$g_{y_1}=\int g(y_1,y_2) \,dY_2=\int\limits_y_1^1y_2 \, dy_2=\frac{1-y_1^2}{2},0<y_1<1$$

I'm not feeling confident in my solution. I would greatly appreciate any feedback on my attempt. Thank you.

Comment: The attempt has problems. The answer does not have a reasonable shape, the density should not have $Y_2$, indeed no $Y_1$, caps should be reserved for random variables. And it is clear that the ratio can be large, so a density of shape $\frac{1-w^2}{2}$ is impossible, since this is negative if $w\gt 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Is the reasoning correct before integral is performed?

Comment: The setup is also not right. One *can* use transformations techniques. In my opinion, however, travelling through the cdf is more intuitive.

Comment: The method that I performed is the only way that I have seen this type of problem be solved. I have been trying to work through Sasha's explanation below, but I am not familiar with the notation. So I'm make to the beginning. Could you please be more specific to where my mistake is (ie matrix, limits, etc). Thanks!

Comment: There are some specific small mistakes one could point to, but the main problem is conceptual.  The answer I would have written up would be in some sense the same as Sasha's, with very big difference of style, stressing the geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of problem where beginners can benefit greatly by **drawing a diagram** instead of trying to do it all via symbolic manipulation. It takes
a lot more time to type in the detailed instructions (given below)
of what to do than to simply work with a diagram.

Consider that the joint density has value $\frac 14$ on the interior
of the square with opposite
corners at $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$. So **draw** $x$ and $y$ axes and mark off this
square.  The random point $(X,Y)$ lies somewhere inside this square.

What values can $Z = \frac YX$ take on? Obviously the values of $Z$ are in $(0,\infty)$. For any fixed real number $r \in (0,\infty)$, what is the value of
$$F_Z(r) = P\{Z \leq r\} = P\left\{\frac YX \leq r\right\}
= P\{Y \leq rX\}?$$

We are asking for the probability that the point $(X,Y)$ lies **below**
the line $y = rx$ in the plane that you are sketching. So, **pick**
your favorite real number $r$ and **draw** the line $y=rx$ on your
diagram. (This line necessarily passes through the origin, a.k.a. the
lower left corner of the square). Now, depending on your choice of $r$, 
this line will cross either the horizontal side $y=2$ of the square
at the point $\left(\frac 2r,2\right)$, or the vertical side $x=2$
at $(2,2r)$, and if you think about it just a bit, you will realize
that which of these two cases occurs depends on whether $r > 1$ or $r < 1$.

So, for *any* $r, 0 < r \leq 1$, $P\{Y \leq rX\}$ is the probability that
the random point $(X,Y)$ lies in the interior of the triangle with
vertices $(0,0), (2,0), (2,2r)$ which can be found **in general** by
integrating the joint pdf over this triangle. In this case, if we
put our brain in gear before putting pen to paper, we realize that
the answer can be obtained by simple mensuration. The triangle has
area $\frac 12\times 2\times 2r = 2r$ and since the pdf has constant
value $\frac 14$ on this triangle, we have that 
$$F_Z(r) = P\{Y \leq rX\} = \frac r2, ~ 0 < r \leq 1. \tag{1}$$

We can do a similar computation for the case $1 \leq r < \infty$ with
the slight twist that it is just a little easier to calculate
$P\{Y > rX\} = 1-F_Z(r)$, which is the probability
that the random point lies in the interior of the triangle
with vertices $(0,0), (0,2), \left(\frac 2r,2\right)$. This triangle has
area $\frac 12 \times 2 \times \frac 2r = \frac 2r$ and so
$$F_Z(r) = P\{Y \leq rX\} = 1-\frac{1}{2r}, ~ 1 \leq r < \infty. \tag{2}$$
As a sanity check, note that $(1)$ and $(2)$ both claim that
$F_Z(1) = \frac 12$, and of course, the result matches Sasha's answer.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to explain the details of this problem. I fully understand now.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R=\frac{X_1}{X_2}$. Let's find the cumulative distribution function of $R$. For $r>0$
$$
   F_R(r) = \Pr\left(R \leqslant r\right) = \Pr\left(\frac{X_1}{X_2} \leqslant r \right) = 
   \Pr\left(X_1 \leqslant r X_2\right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \min\left(1, \frac{r}{2} X_2\right) \right)
$$
The last equality follows because $F_{X_1}(x) = \frac{1}{2} \min\left(2, \max\left(0,x\right)\right)$. Now, explicitly writing out the expectation as integral:
$$
  F_R(r) = \mathbb{E}\left( \min\left(1, \frac{r}{2} X_2\right) \right) = \int_0^2 \min\left(1, \frac{r}{2} x_2\right) f_{X_2}\left(x_2\right) \mathrm{d}x_2
$$
Since $f_{X_2}(x_2) = \frac{1}{2} [0 <x_2<2]$, we have
$$
  F_R(r) = \int_0^2 \min\left(1, \frac{r}{2} x_2\right) \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{d}x_2\stackrel{u=x_2/2}{=} \int_0^1 \min\left(1, r u\right)  \mathrm{d}u
$$
Now, consider separate cases of $0<r\leqslant 1$ and $r>1$, getting
$$
   F_R(r) = \begin{cases} \frac{r}{2} & 0 <r \leqslant 1 \cr 1- \frac{1}{2 r} & r > 1 \cr 0 & r \leqslant 0\end{cases}
$$
Differentiating the cumulative distribution function we can recover the PDF:
$$
  f_R(r) =  \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} & 0 <r \leqslant 1 \cr \frac{1}{2 r^2} & r > 1 \cr 0 & r \leqslant 0\end{cases}
$$

Comment: The method I attempted to use to solve the problem was the only way I have seen a similar problem performed. I am unfamiliar with your method, but I am sure that your work shows the correct answer. Thank you for your time and your very detailed explanation.

Comment: I've been working with your notation for many hours now and I am still having a difficult time understanding exactly what you are doing with the $min(1,\frac{r}{2}x_2)\frac{1}{2}$ for when $r>1$. Could you please show how you came to that solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{z \equiv {X_{1} \over X_{2}}}$. The answer $\ds{\pp\pars{z}}$ is given by:
\begin{align}
\pp\pars{z}&=\int_{0}^{2}\half\int_{0}^{2}\half\delta\pars{z - {X_{1} \over X_{2}}}
\,\dd X_{1}\,\dd X_{2}
={1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}
{\delta\pars{X_{2} - X_{1}/z} \over \verts{X_{1}/X_{2}^{2}}}
\,\dd X_{2}\,\dd X_{1}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 4z^{2}}\int_{0}^{2}X_{1}\int_{0}^{2}
\delta\pars{X_{2} - {X_{1} \over z}}\,\dd X_{2}\,\dd X_{1}
=\left.{1 \over 4z^{2}}\int_{0}^{2}X_{1}\,\dd X_{1}\right\vert
_{\, 0\ <\ X_{1}/z\ <\ 2}
\\[5mm]&=\left.{1 \over 4z^{2}}\int_{0}^{2}X_{1}\,\dd X_{1}\right\vert
_{z\ >\ 0 \atop{\vphantom{\LARGE A}X_{1}\ <\ 2z}}
=\left.{1 \over 4z^{2}}\int_{0}^{\min\pars{2,2z}}X_{1}\,\dd X_{1}
\right\vert_{\, z\ >\ 0}
=\left.{\bracks{\min\pars{2,2z}}^{2} \over 8z^{2}}\right\vert_{\, z\ >\ 0}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
{1 \over 2} & \mbox{if} & 0 < z < 1
\\[2mm]
{1 \over 2z^{2}} & \mbox{if} & z \geq 1
\\[2mm]
0 && \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}
[image]